# Scroll-up button in AngularJS + Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-material

There is such button on [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org/) site! It designed as **md-fab-button** - round red at the bottom right. I can't understand where is the code of this button - there is no description..

An example code snippet using `AngularJS` + `Material` without scroll-up button, the same as I use:

```js
'use strict';
const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
application.controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', function(scope) { }]);
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <!-- Top menu -->
  <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2" md-scroll-shrink>
    <!-- Main -->
    <a href="https://example.com/">
      <md-button>
        <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
      </md-button>
    </a>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content flex layout="column">
    <!-- Page header -->
    <div>
      <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
        <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
          <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page content -->
    <div layout="column" layout-padding layout-wrap style="flex-grow: inherit;">
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
      </div>
      <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
        <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
      </div>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
      <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
      <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
      <!-- Divider -->
      <div flex></div>
    </div>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of the original button is available here: [Material design for AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/material). Inside there is used undocumented factory **$mdUtil** for scrolling, additional custom directive **docsScrollClass** for visual effects and a bit of custom CSS.

**BUT!** In my case, this code won't work properly since the **md-scroll-shrink** attribute is used, i.e. header shrinks away as the user scrolls down.

---

The original code looks something like this:

```js
'use strict';
const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
application
  .controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdUtil',
    function(scope, mdUtil) {
      let mainContentArea = document.querySelector("main");
      let scrollContentEl =
        mainContentArea.querySelector('md-content[md-scroll-y]');
      scope.scrollTop = function() {
        mdUtil.animateScrollTo(scrollContentEl, 0, 200);
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive('docsScrollClass', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        let scrollParent = element.parent();
        let isScrolling = false;

        // Initial update of the state.
        updateState();

        // Register a scroll listener, which updates the state.
        scrollParent.on('scroll', updateState);

        function updateState() {
          let newState = scrollParent[0].scrollTop !== 0;

          if (newState !== isScrolling) {
            element.toggleClass(attr.docsScrollClass, newState);
          }

          isScrolling = newState;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.md-fab.docs-scroll-fab {
  position: fixed !important;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.docs-scroll-fab.scrolling {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" flex class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <main layout="column" flex>
    <!-- Top menu without md-scroll-shrink-->
    <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2">
      <a href="https://example.com/">
        <md-button>
          <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
        </md-button>
      </a>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex layout="column" md-scroll-y>
      <!-- Page header -->
      <div flex="noshrink">
        <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
          <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
            <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Page content -->
      <div layout="column" layout-padding layout-wrap>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
        </div>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <!-- Divider -->
        <div flex></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Scroll-up fub-button -->
      <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right docs-scroll-fab" docs-scroll-class="scrolling" ng-click="scrollTop()" aria-label="Back to Top">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Back to Top</md-tooltip>
        <span>Top</span>
      </md-button>
    </md-content>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

My case:

```js
'use strict';
const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
application
  .controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdUtil',
    function(scope, mdUtil) {
      let mainContentArea = document.querySelector("main");
      let scrollContentEl =
        mainContentArea.querySelector('md-content[md-scroll-y]');
      scope.scrollTop = function() {
        mdUtil.animateScrollTo(scrollContentEl, 0, 200);
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive('docsScrollClass', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        let scrollParent = element.parent();
        let isScrolling = false;

        // Initial update of the state.
        updateState();

        // Register a scroll listener, which updates the state.
        scrollParent.on('scroll', updateState);

        function updateState() {
          let newState = scrollParent[0].scrollTop !== 0;

          if (newState !== isScrolling) {
            element.toggleClass(attr.docsScrollClass, newState);
          }

          isScrolling = newState;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.md-fab.docs-scroll-fab {
  position: fixed !important;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.docs-scroll-fab.scrolling {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" flex class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <main layout="column" flex>
    <!-- Top menu with md-scroll-shrink-->
    <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2" md-scroll-shrink>
      <a href="https://example.com/">
        <md-button>
          <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
        </md-button>
      </a>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content flex layout="column" md-scroll-y>
      <!-- Page header -->
      <div flex="noshrink">
        <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
          <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
            <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Page content -->
      <div layout="column" layout-padding layout-wrap>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
        </div>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <!-- Divider -->
        <div flex></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Scroll-up fub-button -->
      <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right docs-scroll-fab" docs-scroll-class="scrolling" ng-click="scrollTop()" aria-label="Back to Top">
        <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Back to Top</md-tooltip>
        <span>Top</span>
      </md-button>
    </md-content>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

#### Solution:

Pull out the button outside from **md-content** - leave it in **main**. Don't change factory **$mdUtil** and custom CSS - update directive **docsScrollClass**, because there is a well-done scroll button, but it displays badly.

Get the following structure:

```xml
<main>
    <!-- Top menu with or without md-scroll-shrink-->
    <md-toolbar>
        . . .
    </md-toolbar>

    <!-- Page content with scroll -->
    <md-content>
        . . .
    </md-content>

    <!-- Scroll-up fub-button -->
    <md-button>
        . . .
    </md-button>
</main>
```

This code will work with both on and off **md-scroll-shrink**:

```js
'use strict';
const application = angular.module("application", ['ngMaterial']);
application
  .controller('applicationCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdUtil',
    function(scope, mdUtil) {
      let mainContentArea = document.querySelector("main");
      let scrollContentEl =
        mainContentArea.querySelector('md-content[md-scroll-y]');
      scope.scrollTop = function() {
        mdUtil.animateScrollTo(scrollContentEl, 0, 200);
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive('scrollClass', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {

        let scrollMainChildren = element.parent().children();
        let isScrolling = false;

        // Initial update of the state.
        updateState();

        // Register a scroll listener, which updates the state.
        scrollMainChildren.on('scroll', updateState);

        function updateState() {
          // md-content element
          let newState = scrollMainChildren[1].scrollTop !== 0;
          if (newState !== isScrolling) {
            element.toggleClass(attr.scrollClass, newState);
          }

          isScrolling = newState;
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.md-fab.scroll-fab {
  position: fixed !important;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.scroll-fab.scrolling {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.20/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="application" ng-controller="applicationCtrl" ng-init="onInit();" layout="column" flex class="ng-cloak" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <main layout="column" flex>
    <!-- Top menu with md-scroll-shrink-->
    <md-toolbar class="md-toolbar-tools md-hue-2" md-scroll-shrink>
      <a href="https://example.com/">
        <md-button>
          <b class="md-title">Main page</b>
        </md-button>
      </a>
    </md-toolbar>
    <!-- Page content with scroll -->
    <md-content flex layout="column" md-scroll-y>
      <!-- Page header -->
      <div>
        <div layout="row" flex="100" md-whiteframe="1">
          <div flex layout="row" layout-margin layout-align="center center">
            <span class="md-display-1">Learning to write programs</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Page content -->
      <div layout="column" layout-padding flex>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello world</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello space</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello universe</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello Santa Claus</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello stars</span>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" md-whiteframe="1">
          <span class="md-display-1">Hello everyone</span>
        </div>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <span>Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.</span>
        <!-- Divider -->
        <div flex></div>
      </div>
    </md-content>
    <!-- Scroll-up fub-button -->
    <md-button class="md-fab md-fab-bottom-right scroll-fab" scroll-class="scrolling" ng-click="scrollTop()" aria-label="Back to Top">
      <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Back to Top</md-tooltip>
      <span>Top</span>
    </md-button>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

See «[Scroll-up fab-button](https://drakonoved.org/blog/2020/03/08/scroll-up-fab-button.html)»